# Wiki Application for CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, wiki, wiki-engine

I'm looking into doing a project for someone, and they want to implement a wiki into their site. I plan on building the site using Code Igniter, and I was hoping there was some kind of Wiki Application available, but I have not yet been able to find one. Does anybody know of one, or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand that you might want to learn to implement a large-scale app in CodeIgniter. However, in the case of a wiki, don't re-invent the wheel! There are [tons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki_%28software%29) of already available wiki software for you to use.

A few of the best that are written in PHP include:

- PmWiki
- dokuwiki
- MediaWiki (used by Wikipedia)

This way you can integrate these well produced systems, which have a wealth of documentation to your advantage. Instead of wasting time creating the entire wiki from scratch, you can just integrate the rest of your CodeIgniter application into one of these ready-made offerings. Saving you some time, learning about their inner workings and giving your client/friend a better overall system.

Answer (score 2):

Expression Engine is built on CodeIgniter and includes a wiki module.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in CodeIgniter, but you can include the classes in the [Text_Wiki PEAR package](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Wiki).

The PEAR page has almost zero documentation, but there seems to be a lot of information [here](http://pear.reversefold.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=text_wiki).

This will just do the conversion of wiki markup to html. You have to do the image uploads, page views, permissions, etc yourself.